# I receive a mixed cell width error once again

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Sub Demo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim r as Long
    Dim C As Range
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        For r = 2 To .Rows.Count

            With .Rows(r)
                If .Cells.Count < 5 Then .Cells(2).Delete
                If .Cells.Count > 4 Then .Cells(3).Delete

            End WIth
        Next
        ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,2).Delete
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where are you getting the error?

Comment: If you want further interaction with macropod, who answered a question for you, it would be best for you to write a COMMENT to that answer. OR, if you write a new question, you need to include ALL the relevant information in the question or post a LINK to the previous question if that's still relevant. As it stands, tis new question is unclear as it does not contain all the necessary information. Also, pay attention to the TAGS you use: `word` is NOT a valid tag for questions about Microsoft Word - it says so in the text that appears when you type that tag.

Comment: Wrong code..With .Rows(r)
If .Cells.Count < 3 Then
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(2).Width = InchesToPoints(4)
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(3).Width = InchesToPoints(2)

End If
If .Cells.Count > 4 Then
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(2).Width = InchesToPoints(4)
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(3).Width = InchesToPoints(2)
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(4).Width = InchesToPoints(3)
End If
End With

Comment: I want the macro to adjust the column width

Comment: ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(2).Width = InchesToPoints(4)

Comment: I want the macro to adjust the column width

Comment: I receive the error during compilation time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I indicated in your other thread, the process has to be done at the cell level. Thus:

```
        With .Rows(r)
            If .Cells.Count < 3 Then
                .Cells(2).Width = InchesToPoints(4)
                .Cells(3).Width = InchesToPoints(2)
            ElseIf .Cells.Count > 4 Then
                .Cells(2).Width = InchesToPoints(4)
                .Cells(3).Width = InchesToPoints(2)
                .Cells(4).Width = InchesToPoints(3)
            End If
        End With
```

Comment: yes after awhile, I notice that I was manipulating the columns, not the cells:

Comment: ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(3).Width